# TypeError: this.state is not iterable in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I want to store multiple input field form data in `localstorage` on submit click and show in another component.

```
 <code>
 handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.state);
    if (formValid(this.state)) {
      console.error("Form is valid");
      localStorage.setItem("userSubmit", ...this.state);
    } else {
      console.error("Form is invalid");
    }
  };
 </code>
```

Comment: try to use just localStorage.setItem("userSubmit", this.state);

Comment: Try this: `localStorage.setItem("userSubmit", JSON.stringify(this.state));`

Comment: You cannot call a function using the spread operator over an object. That is the problem you are facing. If it was an array it would be fine but the expected behaviour will be not your desired one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.state` is probably an Object, which is - indeed - not iterable (and therefore you can't use the spread operator on it).

If you want to store an object in the `localStorage`, you can store it as a string, using:

```
localStorage.setItem("userSubmit", JSON.stringify(this.state));
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are calling a function (in this case setItem) using the spread operator over an plain Object. You cannot do that.

You are trying to do this:

```
state = { name: 'stack', lastname: 'overflow' }

localStorage.setItem('myKey', name: 'stack', lastname: 'overflow')
```

That has no sense and you are doing it there.

The spread operator is valid for an array for example:

```
state = ['stack', 'overflow']

localStorage.setItem('myKey', 'stack', 'overflow')
```

In that case the call will be valid but the final result will be storing 'stack' and overflow will be igonored and it will not be saved in localStorage.

You need to change your code to:

This will store the string [object Object].

```
localStorage.setItem("userSubmit", this.state);
```

that is an error (you do not want it) so, you will need to store your object stringified

```
localStorage.setItem("userSubmit", JSON.stringify(this.state));
```

Answer (score 0):

You already got a few good answers on how to fix this (Stringify is a good idea), but why does your approach not work?

Have a look at the MDN article about the spread operator: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

As you can see, you can only spread objects into other objects. Not into Arrays or functions for example. Why is that the case? I guess because the sread operator tries to spread key value pairs into key values.

That also brings us to another possible solution:

`localStorage.setItem("userSubmit", Object.values(this.state));`

That way you create an values array from the state. Of course, that only is useful if you only need the values without the corresponding keys, otherwise, the stringify method is still better.